# Rails - Add a 'GET' sub-route to a main route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have a route called `requests` that may have GET/POST endpoints. But another requirement is to achieve the following format: `/api/requests/sync`.

I tried the following in `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :requests do
    get "sync"
  end
end
```

But this gives me the following format:

> /requests/:request_id/sync

How can I create a sub-route as `requests/sync` without having it as a sub-route of `/:request_id/sync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions). Specifically, collection routes. You'll do something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :requests do
    collection do 
      get "sync"
    end
  end
end
```

Which will give you `requests/sync`

To pick up on the `sync_controller` question...

Personally, not knowing much about what you're actually up to, I would keep `sync` as an action on the `requests_controller`. Something like:

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def sync
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

While `sync` is *not* one of the standard RESTful actions, it seems more natural to me than creating a new controller. In general, but not always, I think of controllers as being noun-oriented (e.g., 'request', in your case) and actions being verb-oriented. "Sync" seems way more verb-y to me than noun-y.

You *could* do something along the lines of what Cyzanfar suggests. But, I would suggest you ask yourself:

- Do you need all the standard actions for your would-be `sync_controller`?
- Is there some meaningful reason to inherit from `Requests::RequestsController`?
- Do you even *need* `Requests::RequestsControler` or could you just do `RequestsController` and then have `Requests::SyncController` inherit from `RequestsController` (which seems less tortured to me)?
- And probably other important questions I'm not thinking about on-the-fly.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. One last extension from this: How can I create a controller for `sync`? Is it placed within the same controller of `requests` or is it a separate controller?

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is a namespace. You'd have a parent requests controller and a child sync controller. Would you like me to show you how to do that?

Comment: Yes please :) @Cyzanfar Can you update the answer with that?

Comment: I agree with the naming convention you discussed here. `sync` delivers an array of individual `Request` data so it's part of the `RequestsController`. Defining it inside the same controller makes more sense in this context. Thank you for the detailed explanation jvillian!

Comment: BTW, I'm a big TWD fan.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to achieve this with namespacing your controllers so that you can have a distinct controller for `sync` and `requests` where the request controller will act as the parent (base) controller.

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :requests do
 resources :sync
end
```

**requests/requests_controller.rb**

```
class Requests::RequestsController < ApplicationController
end
```

**requests/sync_controller.rb**

```
class Requests::SyncController < Requests::RequestsController
end
```

Now you'll have the nested CRUD paths under requests

*/requests/sync/new*

*/requests/sync/index*

*/requests/sync/create*
...

Comment: Yes this is another way! Thank you for the detailed answer, mate! :)

Comment: you are very welcome @RickGrimesTheCoder. happy coding!